# Inverse Fourier transform relation for $L^2$ function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

If $f$ is an $L^2$ function and $\hat{f}$, its Fourier transform, also in $L^2$, can the Fourier transform and its inverse be written as

$$\hat{f}(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) e^{i\omega x}dx$$

and

$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \hat{f}(\omega) e^{-i\omega x}d\omega$$

respectively, disregarding the constants? When can a Fourier transform and its inverse exist, but the above definitions not hold?

Comment: Hmm, $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$. Otherwise the integrand does not have the be integrable.

Comment: @Jonas T: Plancherel helps you to extend the notion of the Fourier transform to all of $L^2$ (like it is conventionally done). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Generalizations

Comment: @Fabian: Yes, by density. And then by interpolation for $1 < p < 2$. But if you have an explicit integral, doesn't it need to have a meaning then? The question is if it can be written like this.

Comment: @Jonas T: I agree if the notation means "integral", it does not have a meaning. If it means "fourier transform" then it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jonas T already hit on the important point that for the first integral to be defined, $f$ must be in $L^1$. Similarly, for the second integral to be defined, $\hat{f}$ must be in $L^1$.

Fabian has mentioned that the Fourier tranform [can be generalized](http://eom.springer.de/f/f041170.htm) even beyond $L^2$.  But if you're only concerned with $L^2$, then one way to define the Fourier transform is to first show that it defines an isometric (with respect to the $L^2$ norm) isomorphism on the [Schwartz space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space), which is dense in $L^2$, and then take the unique extension to all of $L^2$.  The fact that the Fourier transform defines an isometry with dense range on a dense subspace of $L^2$, and thus has a unique extension to a unitary operator on $L^2$, is known as [Plancherel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plancherel%27s_theorem).  I have only mentioned one approach, which is the one I learned from Chapter 10 of J.B. Conway's *[A course in functional analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=ix4P1e6AkeIC&dq=a+course+in+functional+conway&source=gbs_navlinks_s)*.

So the answer to your final question, at least restricted to $L^2$, is that every element of $L^2\setminus L^1$ provides an example, strictly speaking.  However, you can show that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^R f(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx$ converges to $\hat{f}(\omega)$ in $L^2$ norm as $R\to\infty$, and similarly $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^R \hat{f}(\omega)e^{i\omega x}dx$ converges to $f(x)$ in $L^2$ norm as $R\to\infty$.  I don't have a reference to a proof handy, but this and more is summarized in the Springer online encyclopedia's [article on the Fourier transform](http://eom.springer.de/f/f041150.htm), which includes helpful references and links.

Comment: A good book for non-measure theoretic Fourier analysis is "Fourier Analysis" by Stein & Shakarchi.

Comment: I think I understand most of what you say. What exactly does "dense in $L^2$" mean?

Comment: Dense in the sense of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set.  One way to think of it in this particular situation is this: A linear subspace $V\subseteq L^2$ is dense if every element of $L^2$ is a limit in the $L^2$ norm of a sequence in $V$.  In other words, every element of $L^2$ can be approximated arbitrarily closely by elements of $V$.  In my answer, I refer to the fact that the Schwartz space is dense in $L^2$, and in fact the space of smooth functions with compact support is dense in $L^2$, as came up in another question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8504/

Comment: I also refer to the fact that a continuous linear transformation on a dense subspace has a unique continuous extension to the whole space.  More generally, a uniformly continuous function defined on a dense subspace of a metric space has a unique continuous extension to the whole space.

Comment: The two links to `eom.springer.de` in this post are broken. I suggested an edit fixing these links, but the edit suggestion was [rejected](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1806874) in review. For future readers, the two links should point to '[Fourier transform of a generalized function](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Fourier_transform_of_a_generalized_function)' and '[Fourier transform](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)'.

Answer (score 2):

There are many cases when the Fourier transform can be defined and the function is not $L^2$. Take  a look at [tempered distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) for a class of "functions" for which the Fourier transform and its inverse can be defined. The most prominent example is the delta function (distribution).